# Java web application or java desktop application

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, remote-server

Is it a stable solution to connect Java desktop Application with a mysql database on a remote server.... ? ASP.NET and php are out of options....OR Is it wise to use JAVA web application instead of desktop application to connect to remote mysql server? I have already tried and developed Java Desktop Applications with mysql on localhost, Is Java web application is like programming in desktop applications?

Comment: Desktop application or Web Application? It will depend what your application users wants/needs. Also, if the connection with MySQL must be centralized somewhere, then I would recommend having a Web Application or an application that communicates with the database and provides this operations through services and then having a client application (Web or Desktop).

Comment: "Is it a stable solution to connect Java desktop Application with a mysql database on a remote server" <-- almost never in corporate environments and their generally asstight policy of internet access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes.

Note that basically this design is only valid in a trusted environment.  If there is *any* possibility that the application can be used by people who have any incentive to hack the database used, you MUST protect your database.

It is trivially simple to look at unprotected network traffic between your application and your database, and get the access credentials.  Then it is trivially simple to establish your own connection and do anything the database allows for those credentials.  This can be quite a lot unless you are prepared for it.

I would suggest having a frontend to your database with code under your control which does only the operations your application needs.  An easy way to do this is with java application server clients if you run a Java EE server like Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have achieved what you want. You wanted to connect to the mysql database and you are able to do so. As you have said : "I have already tried and developed Java Desktop Applications with mysql on localhost"

I hope you understand the difference between Desktop application and a web application.  Here is a good article for you to understand the pros and cons of both :

http://valums.com/web-apps/